# ¿el formulario se llena , pero cuando le doy enviar al formulario no deja enviar?

Tags: php, html

HTML Anexado(anexe solo la parte  donde quiero que capture los valores en este caso son los inputs Type text

```
  <div class="t945">
    <div class="adaptable">
    <div class="Form-Corp">
       <form id="form1"  action="send.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="Form-Caja" >
          <div class="Form-Principal">
           <h1 class="Form-Title">Arma Tu Pizza</h1>
           </div>
           <input type="text" id="input-totalmente-falso" style="display: none">
           <label for="Nombre" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autofocus autocomplete="off" id="Nombre" class="Input-Form" name="Name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
           <label for="Correo" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Correo" class="Input-Form" name="Correo" placeholder="Correo" required>
           <label for="Direccion" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Direccion" class="Input-Form" name="Direccion" placeholder="Direccion" required>
           <label for="Elige tu Sabor" class="Form-Label"></label>
            <!---------------------------------->

           <!---------------------------------->
           <input type="radio" class="button1" name="Pago" value="EFECTIVO" checked><p class="PA-1">Efectivo</p><br>
           <input type="radio" class="button2" name="Pago" value="PUNTO DE VENTA" checked><p class="PA-2">Punto De Venta</p><br>
           <a href="javascript:PRICE()"><input type="button" id="Consultar" class="Input-Price" value="Calcular Precio"></a>
           <div class="tot">
              <label class="DIV" for="txtValor"></label>
              <input  type="text" name="tot" readonly id="txtValor" value="0" />
          </div>
           <input  id="SEND" type="image"  img src="send.png" height="50px" width="50px" class="Boton-Submit" name="Submit" value="SEND">
           <p class="Form-Label1">PEDIDOS</p>




    <div class="wrapper1">
    <h3>Selecciona tus ingredientes</h3>
  <div class="sub_wrapper1">
    <div class="hobby1">
      <label class="container1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Jamon">
        <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
        <img  class="fas1" src="jamon.png"  width="30px" height="30px">
        <p>Jamon</p>
         </label>

    <div class="hobby1">
      <label class="container1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Pepperoni">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
      <img  class="fas1" src="pepperoni.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
     <p>Pepperoni</p>
     </label>

    <div class="hobby1">
      <label class="container1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Tocineta">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
      <img  class="fas1" src="tocino.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
       <p>Tocineta</p>
       </label>

    <div class="hobby1">
      <label class="container1"> 
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Maiz">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
      <img  class="fas1" src="maize.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
      <p>Maiz</p>
      </label>


    <div class="hobby1">
      <label class="container1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Champiñon">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
      <img  class="fas1" src="champi%C3%B1on.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
       <p>Champiñon</p>
       </label>


       <div class="hobby1">
       <div class="menuB1">
      <label class="container1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Cebolla">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
      <img  class="fas1" src="cebolla.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
       <p>cebolla</p>
       </label>
       </div>


        <div class="hobby1">
       <div class="menuB1">
      <label class="container1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Pimenton">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
       <img  class="fas1" src="pimenton.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
       <p>Pimenton</p>
       </label>
       </div>



        <div class="hobby1">
       <div class="menuB1">
      <label class="container1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Piña">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
      <img  class="fas1" src="pi%C3%B1a.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
       <p>Piña</p>
       </label>
       </div>



        <div class="hobby1">
       <div class="menuB1">
      <label class="container1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Pizza Pequeña">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
      <img  class="fas1" src="pizza.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
       <p>Pequeña</p>
       </label>
       </div>




        <div class="hobby1">
       <div class="menuB1">
      <label class="container1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input1" name="modulo[]" id="modulo" value="Pizza Grande">
      <span class="d_checkbox1"></span>
      <img  class="fas1" src="pizza-2.png" title="" width="30px" height="30px">
       <p>Grande</p>
       </label>
       </div>




               </div>       
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>  
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
    $Destino = "alguien@gmail.com";  


     //asignando data from $_POST array a variables 
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
      //Obtenemos valores input formulario
      $Nombre       = $_POST['Name'];
      $email        = $_POST['Correo']; 
      $Delivery     = $_POST['Direccion'];
      $Method       = $_POST['Pago'];
      $TOTAL        = $_POST['tot'];
      $Contenido= "Nombre :" . $Nombre . "\nCorreo: " . $email . "\nDireccion: " . $Delivery . "\nMetodo De Pago: " . $Method . "\TOTAL A PAGAR: " . $TOTAL; 




    //$host_plan = $_POST['radio_group_1'];//
    $Select = implode(' | ', $_POST['modulo']); 
    //$host_period = $_POST['dropdown'];// 

    // construyendo el asunto del email// 
    $Subject = 'PEDIDOS A MAXIPIZZA' ; //. $name;//

    //enviando Checkbnox Selectivos 
    $body_message  =  "PEDIDO DEL USUARIO : "  . $Select; 



    //$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n"; 
    //$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n"; 

    $mail_sent = mail($Destino, $Subject,"contacto",$body_message,$Contenido); 

        if ($mail_sent == true){ ?> 
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
           alert('TU PEDIDO SE REALIZO CON EXITO'); 
           window.location = 'index.html'; 
        </script> 
    <?php  } else { ?> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
          alert('No se completo el registro intentelo otra vez'); 
          window.location = 'index.html'; 
    </script> 
    <?php 
    } 

    }

?>
```

les explico  yo lleno el formulario completo y a pesar de estar lleno me sale el alert que puse en el php `alert('No se completo el registro intentelo otra vez'); 
          window.location = 'index.html';`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

eso me indica que no está recogiendo los campo de los inputs text, ¿pero algo tendrá mal el php? ** donde dice Obtenemos valores input formulario** esa linea la agrege para que me capturara los datos de los input text, no se si esa parte este mal escrita o es incorrecto ponerla  el formulario contiene checkbox y text y deseo que ambos se envíen

Comment: Anexa tu codigo html de la seccion del form, puede que ahi se encuentre tu error y que alguien pueda responder a tu duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto parece un error de la funcion mail de PHP, si estas haciendo pruebas en un entorno local tipo XAMPP te va a mandar ese error, necesitarias instalar algun plugin adicional y configurar XAMPP para habilitar la funcion de mail de PHP. Este puede integrarse con XAMPP (https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) segun lo que se lee en: (https://ejemplocodigo.com/ejemplo-xampp-enviar-un-email-en-localhost/).

Si estas en el servidor en linea prueba que mail esta habilitado, no en todos los servidores esta habilitado por defecto, por lo que tendrias que contactar a soporte al cliente para que te lo habiliten.

Prueba con un script de PHP como este "mail.php", subelo a un directorio y ejecutalo.

```php
<?php
$to = "miemail@tudominio.com";
$subject = "Correo de prueba";
$message = "Este es sólo un mensaje de prueba.";
$from = "no-reply@tudominio.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

$send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($send) {
echo "Funcion mail ejecutada";
}
else {
echo "Funcion mail no se ejecuto";
}

?>
```

Añadido:

Como te sugirio Juan Manuel con el volcado del array, estas haciendo la prueba al isset($_POST["submit"]) y este falla por el valor del tipo del input, cambialo a input type="submit" o entonces a button type="submit", y entonces el valor a probar pasara el resto de datos.

```html
<!-- 
<input  id="SEND" type="image"  img src="send.png" height="50px" width="50px" class="Boton-Submit" name="Submit" value="SEND">
-->

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">SEND</button>
```

Revisa los parametros requeridos para que la funcion mail se ejecute correctamente, modifique tu script para que funcionara a:

```php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    # Codigo y mas codigo

    $email = "no-reply@email.com";
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n"; 

    $mail_sent = mail($Destino, $Subject, $body_message, $headers);
```

$Destino, $Subject y $body_message ya los tienes declarados

Comment: lo hice desde el hosting, y el mail esta habilitado  , porque anteriormente Antes de que le pusiera las lineas para capturar los inputs text me enviaba al mail los checkbox seleccionados

Comment: Probaste la funcion mail?

Comment: ya te comento lo que me resulto de la prueba

Comment: **Funcion mail ejecutada** el mail funciono a la perfección

Comment: Hice una prueba con tu script y hay una llave que sale sobrando al cierre del script de PHP, "} }", elimine una de las dos y logre obtener el mensaje de envio correcto

Comment: probe el script quitandole las dos llaves y aun sigue tirándome el problema

Comment: Vale, no me habia fijado en el if inicial

Comment: Estoy viendo algunas fallas semanticas en el formulario, solo para chequear que todo esta bien, cierra el form </form> y ponle el type="submit" al boton "send"

Comment: voy a subir todo el código html , es que solo pase una parte

Comment: Mira la actualizacion de la respuesta

Comment: ya hice los cambios , pero sigue igual con el problema

Comment: Mira aqui -> https://accedo-gps.000webhostapp.com/demo/testing/form.html

Comment: Warning: mail() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given in /storage/ssd5/330/12599330/public_html/send.php on line 35  esto me arrojo

Comment: Ahi te lo dice, estas pasando mas parametros de los que son requeridos para la funcion mail

Comment: ok , dejame corregir a ver que sucede

Comment: bueno ahora si llego el correo con los campos de texto y selecciones de checkbox solo que no me llego dos datos pero ya me las arreglo. Muchas gracias por su ayuda se los agradezco

Answer (score 1):

Además de lo que sugirió AugustoM, hiciste un volcado de la variable $_POST en send.php para asegurarte que todo llega como debe?

Comment: **$_POST** disculpa mi ignorancia pero a que te refieres con volcado de la variable?

Comment: $_POST ($_REQUEST y $_SESSION también) son arrays asociativos. Por las dudas te diría que al principio de send.php pongas lo siguiente:

`
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
`

Solo para asegurarte que realmente estén llegando los datos. Porque por ahí tu problema es ese, tenés algo que se está perdiendo y no llegando a send.php y por eso no manda el mail. Lo más probable es que sea que no tengas habilitada algo para el envío de mails, pero nunca está más descartar otras cosas también.

Comment: hola hice lo que me dijiste y esto es lo que me arrojo , esto me indico que si agarra los valores pero , no se envían ``` Array
(
    [Name] => jesu
    [Correo] => car@gmail.com
    [Direccion] => maior
    [Pago] => PUNTO DE VENTA
    [tot] => 16
    [Submit_x] => 46
    [Submit_y] => 29
    [Submit] => SEND
    [modulo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jamon
            [1] => Maiz
            [2] => Pizza Grande
        )

) ```